# Reference request for philosophical texts on race

Tags: reference-request, society

Is there even such a thing as the philosophy of race, or race viewed from a philosophical point of view? If so, I would like to read some references on the philosophy of race. I would be very interested to hear what philosophers have said about race, racism, and other racial issues. I am not primarily interested in a biological or even sociological perspective on race, I am more interested in the philosophical perspective on race, if there even is such a thing.

Comment: Here are [SEP, Race](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/race/) and [SEP, Critical Philosophy of Race](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/critical-phil-race/) with surveys of philosophical positions and arguments, and multiple references. Even just googling "philosophy of race" returns multiple hits. For a cogent answer here, your request needs to be more specific.

Comment: Sometimes fiction talks clearer than fact. Look to Shakespeare's Othello for a super toxic  mix of race n jealousy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course there is. Biology, social analysis, politics and realpolitik, legal theory and rights discourse, and philosophy intersect. The industrialised genocide of the Holocaust, provides particular grounds for ethical questions and moral dilemmas.

Some related discussions on here:

[Is biological ancestry distinct from race?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/84552/is-biological-ancestry-distinct-from-race/84554#84554)

[Can you explain clearly the difference between race and ethnicity?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97091/can-you-explain-clearly-the-difference-between-race-and-ethnicity/97268#97268)

[What are diversity partitioning and clustering analysis, applied to hominids & race?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/87350/what-are-diversity-partitioning-and-clustering-analysis-applied-to-hominids-r/87378#87378)

[Do decolonialists have to attack science and modernity?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99253/do-decolonialists-have-to-attack-science-and-modernity/99267#99267)

[Are there philosophically serious moral arguments against eugenics?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/75984/are-there-philosophically-serious-moral-arguments-against-eugenics/76006#76006)

[Need help with this paper on epistemic justice](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/87224/need-help-with-this-paper-on-epistemic-justice/87228#87228)

[What is the difference between Subaltern and any other oppressed group?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90382/what-is-the-difference-between-subaltern-and-any-other-oppressed-group/90393#90393)

[Studies exploring the rationale of gender equality](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90227/studies-exploring-the-rationale-of-gender-equality/90235#90235)