# Do decolonialists have to attack science and modernity?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, political-philosophy, marxism, capitalism, anarchism

I’m a professional scientist (mathematician, actually). *I’m not a philosopher*.

I’ve got a lot of friends well-versed in philosophy, and they all seem to point toward modernity as a byproduct of capitalism, the last one being a byproduct itself of colonialism. I’ve always been a left-wing person myself, so I also like decolonialism as an ideology, but I feel that, with this narrative about modernity, decolonialism is starting to attack science itself. The roots of science are very antique, even before the settlement of the first colonies of Europe.

This brings me to the main issue. Science is euro-centric in its core… but only because it sprang in a euro-centric culture. Modern algebra itself has a long tradition coming from Arabian algebraists. Is this conclusion equivalent to science being a colonial posture? Is modernity euro-centric? Are the computer or the lightbulb, “colonial technology”? Am I working against my decolonial ideology just by being a scientist? Do decolonialists have to attack science and modernity?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146012/discussion-on-question-by-simon-flavio-ibanez-do-decolonialists-have-to-attack-s); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: What do you view as "modernity"?

Comment: What's missing from the question is a specific summary of the anti-science argument you are asking us to assess. In the absence of such a summary, the answers inevitably focus on the silliest, weakest possible arguments they can think of to fill that gap.

Comment: You might like 'What are some sociological considerations to understands mathematics culture?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/98734/what-are-some-sociological-considerations-to-understands-mathematics-culture/98748#98748

Comment: - I hate people who claim that imperialism and colonialism are inextricably linked with capitalism. The opposite is true: At the core of capitalism (which I equate here with the less loaded term "market economy") is the free individual. It is well possible that pure capitalism is unstable &mdash; forming monopolies and oscillating too much &mdash; and thus needs constant regulation and intervention to stay stable. But monopolies and oligarchies are a *breakdown* of capitalism, not its logical culmination!
- There certainly are non-imperialist but prototypically capitalist countries, for exampl

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Not sure the cause and effect relation is ultimately settled but there are certainly correlations. Like empires based on military strength might be capped in size due to the speed of power (military). While power in the form of capital can travel at the speed of information which is usually much faster, thus capitalism allows for larger empires, that are less localized (wealth works everywhere) and which require less sharing of power (vassals got means of production, generals got an army, managers get money).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Likewise the "rule of law" and the protection of "property rights" seems to be a vitally necessity for capitalism. While you can certainly trade without that, capitalism isn't just about trade but also, or actually primarily, about the production and investment in the structures that pushed the industrialization would be too risky without. However where are you most likely to find universal laws? Empires. Fractured realms usually have their own rules and customs. Not to mention that the East India Trading company was an empire of it's own.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica And the obvious elephant in the room that those countries to whom the stream of resources was directed to, due to colonialization also happened to be those countries which had a leap in technological and industrial development, which further enabled both capitalism and imperialism as both require or at least are easier to maintain with new technology. So whether they are inextricably linked and whether it's as easy as Marx thought, that excess stuff creates the ability to industrialize or whether there's more to it. There certainly are correlations.

Comment: @haxor789 Sorry, not sure how this text ended up in a comment (keyboard focus where I didn't see it?). Anyway, it is part of what I say in my answer and what you commented about as well. Oh. I see that my answer was deleted. Hm. This was not an attempt to move it to a comment instead ;-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Is science Eurocentric?**

Well, if one means that one pays homage to the language and philosophy of science, yes. The roots of science go back to the Ancient Greeks, and modern science was invented by Europeans in a European lingua franca, Latin in places like Italy, Germany, France, and England. There are some very European-centric notions embedded in the philosophy of science that may rub foreign cultures wrong. For instance, scientists have always been a mix of Christians, agnostics, and atheists, and therefore the religion, the language, the history, the philosophy, and so on have been Eurocentric. So, one can say the traditions of science are firmly rooted in the cultures of Europe including its great tradition of universities which were originally institutions set up by the Catholic Church with it's seat in Rome. Today, the scientific enterprise is taken seriously outside of Europe and North America including China, India, Japan, South Korea, the Middle East, South America, and is at least paid lip service by most countries for obvious reason. The material comforts in life as well as the advanced military capabilities of a nation depend on the various sciences. Obviously, not all countries follow the sciences to its full end including democratic institutions set up by politically autonomous institutions. North Korea has scientists and engineers, but more like in the spirit of the Soviet Union than Cambridge, MIT, Max Planck Institute, and IIT. English is perhaps the lingua franca today, and discourse in German, Spanish, and French sits along side the use of English, though there are no requirements that science be done in a European language. Funding of science is also a function of the wealth of nations, and the Western nations, particularly the US and the EU, are massive bastions of banking built on the system of fractional lending that helped put into motion the colonial era.

> Am I working against my decolonial ideology just by being a scientist? Do decolonialists have to attack science and modernity?

Of course not. The [UN takes decolonization seriously (UN.org)](https://www.un.org/en/global-issues/decolonization), and it certainly doesn't attack science. In fact, it promotes science. Like any political organization, it's open to criticism, but one of them isn't an effort to eliminate colonial rule. The legacy of [colonialism (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/colonialism/#RecRevSetColSta) is far reaching, but it's not a major influence on the day-to-day of average working scientists, and the sciences are never free from political and economic pressures, as the [science of Big Tobacco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Tobacco) in the US demonstrates. From the site:

> When the United Nations was founded in 1945, some 750 million people, nearly a third of the world's population, lived in Territories that were dependent on colonial Powers. Today, there are  17 Non-Self-Governing Territories remaining and fewer than 2 million people live in them. The wave of decolonization, which changed the face of the planet, was born with the UN and represents the world body’s first great success... As a result of decolonization many Territories became independent and joined the UN.

Decolonialism is not about destroying science, but rather stripping colonial and neo-colonial relationships from the politics of former colonies. That being said, scientific and construction funding is often created by major economic powers with the intent of spreading a political [sphere of influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_of_influence). The US has been doing that since it emerged as a global power, and China today has its [Belt and Road Initiative](https://www.cfr.org/backgrounder/chinas-massive-belt-and-road-initiative). [Chinese universities are in ascendancy and dominate in the region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_universities_in_China) in terms of size, students, and funding. India too has a massive science and technology population and [its universities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_universities_in_India) are many and some of them are quite well regarded. Western textbook publishers put out many Chinese-language and Indian-language versions as well as special English-edition version slated for sales in Asia. (I own several of them as a US citizen.)

#### Conflation of Ideas

It's popular among amateur political scientists to conflate several issues. Capitalism is not a political system, it's a financial system. The sciences have members with political views, and there are scientific organizations devoted to political advocacy of science, but the political contamination of the sciences, such as what happened under [Lysenkoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysenkoism), undermines the good work of the sciences generally. Sometimes, as in Russia, Iraq under the Husseins, or in China, politics circumscribes the freedom of scientists, but on the whole scientists in the US, Australia, England and Continental Europe, Japan, South America, and in many other countries and regions can sort the good from the bad, and can look to their own histories when religions or political bodies interfered with the scientific practices. [Critical theory (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/critical-theory/#4) is a lot more nuanced and pluralistic than right-wing pundits will characterize them as, especially modern self-professed libertarians who are the right-wing equivalent of communists.

So, is your career in the mathematics and sciences contributing to the oppression of people in former colonies. Absolutely not, at least not directly. Are there still inequities that have arisen from Western powers colonial and neo-colonical practices? Absolutely. There is still slavery in the world, and multinational corporations still often abuse their economic power, particularly in using sweatshops, resisting workers' rights, and using child labor overseas. But on the upside, the peoples of the Western nations have developed a consciousness of these abuses, and there are at least discussions about eliminating abuses the wealthy perpetrate on the poor. Is that abuse largely at the hands of mathematicians and scientists? Absolutely not.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146032/discussion-on-answer-by-j-d-do-decolonialists-have-to-attack-science-and-moderni); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: "One can say the traditions of science are firmly rooted in the cultures of Europe". Could you expand on that? While a certain scientist may have been a Christian and a French man with his own political views, and I understand that this may have set his priorities as to scientific research, and this may also have influenced whom he collaborated with and what results he was able or not able to achieve, I don't understand how his scientific output - a theorem, for instance, or the model of a natural phenomenon - would be influenced by all of those factors.

Comment: Excellent question. I'll respond by parroting Thomas Kuhn in that there are three metaphysical principles necessary to be a scientist: nature is ordered and rational, humans are rational creatures who can discover truth, and everything is open to question: ideas of the pre-Socratics that shape European thinkers, and are largely responsible for bringing about Comte's statement of positivism. As such, positivistic thinking fundamentally shapes [perceptual and semantic theory-ladenness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory-ladenness) thereby impacting theorems by making them "objective truth".

Comment: @Simone These ideas of rationality and objective and self-evident truth aren't strictly true, but are metaphysical presumptions we tend to share as European thinkers. The Catholic Church eventually co-opted these principles and placed the Christian God at the top of the order and continued the project in Scholasticism using Aristotle's reason as a basis and establishing universities to spread the word. These metaphysical precepts aren't native to the Post-Islam Middle East and to China and the Far East, for instance.

Comment: @Simone So, the very fact that you don't see bias in the "scientific output - a theorem, for instance, or the model of a natural phenomenon [which] would be influenced by all of those factors" is a distinctly European approach to truth, one which has political ramifications that historically haven't gone over well everywhere. It's no coincidence democracies and republics flourished in the Mediterranean after Greek philosophy was born. Naturalism seems to encourage the belief that all men and women are created as intellectual equals. Athens, Venice, and Parliament are all products of naturalism

Comment: @Simone Of course, feminism has had it's work cut out for it bringing parity to women in science, but science tends to have a politically liberating effect. See [Philosophy of Science in Latin America (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/phil-science-latin-america/) and [*The Rise of Early Modern Science* by Toby E. Huff](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tzm8DgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=toby+huff+modern+science&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi21ZTPyvz-AhWcjYkEHRrRBmUQ6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=toby%20huff%20modern%20science&f=false) for more info.

Comment: @JD Very interesting, thank you for explaining. So, the implication is not that gases don't follow the general gas equation or that such an equation is flawed because it is a product of 19th-century French physics and non-physics culture, but that my bias (as a European) is the very acceptance of the general gas equation as a positive truth, even if I accept it may be superseded by future discoveries, which would then become the new positive truth. Am I right? I am curious to understand how a non-positivistic approach to science works, such as the ones you cite from Middle East and China.

Comment: @Simone Strictly speaking, non-positivistic approaches to science tend NOT to work, because if empirical and rational criteria aren't employed in advancing and defending knowledge, then the science is actually pseudoscience. Lysenkoism in the USSR is one good example, but it needn't be the only. Ignaz Semmelweis tried to advance germ theory when miasma theory was prominent in Austria and he faced ostracization. In both China and the post-Islam Middle East, positivist doctrine was (and to some extent is still) a threat to the Confucian and Muslim dogmas. Thus, it's not so much how science...

Comment: works, but rather to what extent the political factions that rely on dogma which maintains social order suppresses the activities of science. Thus, in the modern RPC, science is ["guided" by the authorities](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/science/article/3213939/chinas-communist-party-take-science-and-tech-reins-break-through-us-containment) to strike a balance between its advantages and its threat to the social order much in the same way that the Catholic church regulated natural philosophy between the time of Bruno and Galileo.

Comment: @Simone It should also be noted that this notion of objectivity is probably the grounds for postmodernist claims of the colonizing effects of science, since postmodernism runs counter to objectivity and that foreign cultures with their own distinctive dogmas are often homogenized by embracing positivist thinking since positivism reduces dogmas to "cultural flourishes" displacing them as central truths.

Comment: The beginning of this answer make it sound as if Europe is the only place where any science was done until very recently. This is pretty dismissive of all the scientific and technological developments that there have been in Asia since Antiquity.

Comment: @Stef To be clear, there have been notable developments outside of Europe. Clearly the cradle of civilization isn't in Europe, and China, for instance, has been the seat of a number of modern technologies: fiat and paper currency, gunpowder, a bit of mathematics, etc. But don't you think that the international language of science is English and not Mandarin? Or that modern science begins in the European Renaissance and Enlightenment? Or that the overwhelming majority of modern technology (car, CPU, transistor, phone) is Eurocentric? Or that modern math and physical theory is Eurocentric?

Comment: For better or worse, modernity was invented in Europe and exported to the rest of the world, often at the end of a rifle, sorry. I make no claim of cultural superiority in this response, but merely observe the unassailable fact that European ideas and technology literally led to the conquest of the globe. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns,_Germs,_and_Steel

Comment: @Stef There was one moment in history when science seemed likely to occur in the Middle East after the invention of democracy and philosophy in Athens, the triumph of Macedonian and Roman imperialism in the Middle East, but the politics of Islam essentially prevented it from happening in the same spirit of the Catholic church during the Dark Ages. It was, again, the European university and middle-class society that created modern science. See https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Rise_of_Early_Modern_Science/Tzm8DgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: Modern science and the modern university is a uniquely European practice in origin. Thankfully, that practice rooted in democracy, literacy, and skepticism is now universal on all continents to some degree. And where it is not, you have poverty, ignorance, and authoritarianism to varying degrees.

Answer (score 9):

But even if colonialism is not palatable as it is a power structure of oppression, isn't there room for everybody to enjoy the benefits of lightbulbs (and vaccines, and a lot more)? Wouldn't rejecting science because it arose from a euro-centric context (if it even actually did) not be a case of throwing out the baby with the bathwater?

I think the question has a pragmatic dimension that could cut through the ideological debate: if a vaccine can save the life or your child, should you reject it just because it was invented by a society that also did/does bad things?

A similar, hypothetical question could be: suppose a chemical company was forced to produce chemical weapons that exterminated a lot of people during a war. 80 years later, the company is still in operation, now producing fertilizers. Should the company's fertilizers be rejected because of what long gone management did in the past?

(I do not have the answer, but I think it is a very appropriate philosophical question - I'd be very curious to read more about that)

Comment: You make a strawman of Postcolonial thinking. It's about legacy power structures, but that includes things like epistemic justice.

Comment: @Frank: See eg 'Need help with this paper on epistemic justice' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/87224/need-help-with-this-paper-on-epistemic-justice/87228#87228 I feel like these answers are not reference any *actual* thinkers or perspectives of Postcolonial theorists

Comment: @CriglCragl I don't intend to address _actual_ thinkers of Postcolonialism, but simply think about the question "Is the computer or the lightbulb, “colonial technology”?" which the OP gave.

Comment: @CriglCragl Should we say that it is _epistemically unjust_ that science is the dominant discourse inevitably pushed by some cultures onto others, thereby snuffing out the epistemic voices of those colonized cultures? Or should we say that science is just another universalizing discourse that some societies are using with the (maybe unconscious) intention of dominating others? How do we know that's the intention behind science? It seems we would be entering a highly biased debate with opinions rather than actual facts maybe?

Comment: I downvoted this because it doesn't appear to relate to the question, because the question is terrible.

Answer (score 5):

I think that there are several factors at work here in parallel.

### 1) Colonialism left a bad taste

I think that the colonialism tie is somewhat of a correlation-not-causation effect: the West tried to impose political and economic policies on others, and there is ongoing resentment over that.  Now, when the West tries to tell people how they had ought to act, these claims are viewed with a lot of suspicion.

### 2) Science gives us "is" but not "ought"

I think that as scientists or mathematicians, we often view our activities and positions as "pure" and not culture-based, in some sense, because the science and mathematics are "pure".  I think a little reflection should make clear that although the science may very well be purely "valid" or "invalid" by some objective criteria, these things don't necessarily inform whether we had *ought* to act in a particular way - they only tell us what will happen when we act in that way.

As an example, medical science finds that Covid vaccines are effective at preventing disease.  The evidence here is pretty thorough.  One might naturally make the leap that one had *ought* to get the vaccine, because the science supports getting the vaccine.  However, this conclusion does not follow immediately from the science - we need an additional premise.  The crucial step that was left unsaid in this reasoning is cultural/personal.  That step is the premise that "if getting relatively non-invasive medical procedure X helps prevent disease for self or for wider society, then one had ought to get medical procedure X."  This premise is not scientific or mathematical, it is cultural/personal.  Someone might very well hold the position that "One had ought not to get any medical procedures, because [deity] forbids such things" or whatever.  There is, unfortunately, no science or math to refute this premise, because it is not scientific or mathematical.  On the flip side of that coin, there is no science or math to refute the premise that one had *ought* to get helpful medical procedures done.  These things are simply cultural axioms, in some sense.  We have a long tradition of such procedures in the West - we are often vaccinated heavily when young, there are often laws affecting the behavior of folks with active TB/HIV infections to prevent wanton transmission, people often get preventive procedures done for their personal health and don't think twice about it.  We have a cultural premise, in the West, that medical interventions of a certain class are generally okay.  It is important to recognize, however, that this premise is strictly cultural/personal, and that although the science is there, it does not tell us that we had *ought* to get vaccinated, it only tells us *what will happen* if we do get vaccinated.

Since a great deal of cutting-edge science happens in the West, scientific results are often bundled and tied up in complex ways with Western values.  Scientists don't always do a great job of discerning the "what will happen" from the "what one had ought to do".  The implicit cultural premises are left unsaid, and unexamined.  This, in turn, at the very least can make it *seem like* folks with different "ought to" opinions (cultural, personal, or whatever) are rejecting the science.  Indeed, if it is not clear even to the scientists how to disentangle the cultural premises from the scientific results, then we might reasonably expect others to fail to distinguish these things as well.  When the cultural premises and scientific results are conflated to an extent that ordinary folks don't find it apparent how to separate them, and the cultural premises conflict with their personal beliefs, they are left with only two options: accept the whole package (causing them to reject their own cultural/personal beliefs), or to reject the whole package (causing them to reject the validity of the science).  That they often reject the science, then, should come as no surprise - but it is not because they "reject science", necessarily, in principle; it is because they reject the conclusions of the (science + culturalPremises) and have been presented with an all-or-nothing alternative.

It doesn't help, I think, that the science is often seen only through the filter of journalists or politicians or other third parties.  This tends to really exacerbate the conflation between the cultural premises and the scientific results.

### 3) Math/Science is hard

I think that the vast majority of "folks" don't understand how science is done: They think that science is a list of things to remember and regurgitate on the exam, and have never had the opportunity to see science as a rigorous method of discovery and knowledge creation.  This makes it easy to conflate science with other qualities of the scientist.  It doesn't help that post-colonial cultures tend to have less developed educational systems than in the West.

### tl;dr;

I think with these things, the prevalence of "science rejection" should come as no surprise.

I've not seen any evidence that the "science rejection" effect is stronger in post-colonial cultures when the source is Western.  However, because of 1) and 2) and 3) I would consider it a very probable hypothesis worth testing.  Anyone who can provide citations for science that actually determines the relative strength of the 1) 2) and 3) effects wins 100 internet points.

Comment: aside: **does** medical science show that COVID vaccines are effective in preventing the disease? Lots and lots of vaccinated people have COVID now, and it makes sense because the vaccines was made for SARS-2, but the circulating virus is as different from SARS-2 as SARS-2 is from SARS-1 (some call it SARS-3), so it should be expected to work a little bit but not a lot.

Comment: @user253751 Absolutely. [COVID-19 Vaccine Effectiveness](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/vaccines/effectiveness/work.html) for a landing page on more information. Discussion over the effectiveness of Covid vaccines, however, is better suited for https://biology.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @JD yeah, it's around 40% according to the CDC. Not great, still better than nothing.

Comment: @user253751 40% what?  40% decrease in prevalence between vaxxed/unvaxxed populations is **well** withing the realm of what scientists would call "an effect" - i.e., that the Covid vaccine "is effective at preventing disease".  Possibly I should add a "4) language barriers between science-speak and the vernacular"

Comment: @user253751 That's already a false expectation. Like there's not a single vaccine that works 100% of the time. And even if it has a 99.9% success rate, with 14 billion doses administered there would still be 14 million cases where it doesn't work. So the question is rather does it work at all and does it do more good than harm. And apparently it has a significantly positive effect with regards to preventing severe cases. A nice football comparison is that with a goal keeper, people are still being able to score goals, yet without one that number is likely not going to decrease.

Comment: @haxor789 "X is effective at preventing Y" is generally expected to mean straightforwardly "X prevents Y" rather than "X prevents Y sometimes" or "X has an effect of reducing the amount of Y"

Comment: @user253751 To say "X prevents Y" is most certainly a lie. You're in the realm of science not religion. There are no universal truths. There are only models and they (should) always come with a margin of error. People (usually not scientists) tend to assert the claims of that model with confidence for small margins, but that's about their personal risk assessment, not about science. That being said the vaccine apparently has a significant effect of preventing the disease and as such it is still better than the alternatives... So yeah currently it's the MOST effective, as little as that means.

Comment: @user253751 "is generally expected to mean" this is probably the case when non-scientists are speaking with other non-scientists.  I'm not trying to posit an opinion on what the semantics had ought to be, but when scientists say "is effective at preventing", generally they do NOT mean "prevents", they mean that "there is a measurable effect in prevention between populations.".  They don't even mean that the effect is large, they merely mean that they were able to reliably measure it.  Possibly they had *ought* to phrase things differently, but c'est la langue

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a specific philosophical definition of decolonialism. I've found [a discussion](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/colonialism/#PosColThe) of *decolonization*, but it doesn't address your specific questions. So my answer will be "philosophical" not in citing literature, but in distinguishing two possible meanings of the term, then arguing we, as philosophers, must at a minimum make sure not to conflate them. (It's also wise to name each, but I won't suggest names.)

I'm going to assume you believe the following:

- We should provisionally accept the conclusions of the scientific method, not because of the culture that invented it, but because the method works well;
- Many technologies with a scientific underpinning are beneficial;
- Historical effects of colonialism include the globally widespread acceptance of science and use of such technologies;
- Historical effects of colonialism also include much that has been socioeconomically pernicious (these are what the above link cares about);
- The latter effects warrant addressing with suitable policies today.

If I'm right, it would make sense to describe you as a decolonialist, but also to describe as decolonialists any people who instead believe:

- Anything colonialism has spread is as bad as its worst socioeconomic effects, and can be labelled as European;
- Therefore, science is bad, and European;
- Therefore, we can feel free to reject any scientific finding we personally dislike, especially if we're not European (or maybe that should be "neither European nor from a mostly white European off-shoot in the Americas or Australia and Oceania");
- If these beliefs are a result of being left-wing, we might, however, shame people for rejecting the scientific findings we personally accept, especially if such people are from our culture and disproportionately likely to be right-wing;
- We'll also keep using the technology, even if its manufacture or distribution exploits non-Europeans, as a vestige of colonialism.

I'm not sure how many people believe the second set.

> Is modernity euro-centric?

It's a historical accident that it developed and spread that way, and if e.g. Africans had been colonialists I would not, as a European, adopt an anti-African counterpart to the second list of beliefs above. (Bonus historical wrinkle: Japan was a colonial power.)

> Are the computer or the lightbulb, “colonial technology”?

I'd be more willing to call them that if colonialists *withheld* them.

> Am I working against my decolonial ideology just by being a scientist?

If as I suspect your personal ideology is as per the first list above rather than the second, no, clearly not.

> Do decolonialists have to attack science and modernity?

Ditto.

Answer (score 3):

**Questions**

> Is this conclusion equivalent to science being a colonial posture? Is modernity euro-centric? Is the computer or the lightbulb, “colonial technology”? Am I working against my decolonial ideology just by being a scientist? Do decolonialists have to attack science and modernity?

**Do decolonialists have to attack science and modernity?**

Speaking as an applied philosopher, a formal student of engineering, law, and technology development, I think scientific and technological progress is accelerated in a Western context where governments, schools, and universities incorporate social institutions primarily associated with ancient Greece. Ideally adults working in government, education, and industry are supporting the youth in their role as athletes and scholars. The youth learn to cooperate and compete. The natives in America had their own cultures of tribal education in which the youth would develop athletic and cognitive abilities. However, the progress of science and technology was inherently limited in those cultures, and the tribes had enemies in the form of nearby tribes. In other words, there was cultural conflict independent of the Westernized "tribes" that imposed customs and institutions in the form of colonialism. Historically it appears that as the Westernized tribes or cultures refrained from overt colonialism, the former colonies remained colonized, because the elite took over the role of colonial overlords. I think decolonialization was first discussed in this context of trying to reform the governments of former colonies. I think nations that want modern standards of living will imitate the United States, Europe, and the so-called Western culture more and more whether the people like it or not, or they will have to develop alternative cultural institutions that also promote the proliferation of modern standards of living. The West will have to adapt also to the rising energy cost of energy derived from scarce fossil fuels and the desire to respect what is unique about distinct cultures that do not wish to assimilate all the Western customs. This does not answer the questions as posed because in the political context some decolonialists will probably say yes, we must attack science and modernity, and others will probably say no, we need not attack science and modernity.

**Ethical Disputes**

Decades ago I had to write a paper on Ethics for a class in Expert Knowledge. I borrowed Schaum's outline from a friend, and read this summary: Ethics is the effort to answer two questions. First, What is good? Second, How should one act to cause the good? In Zen there are debates whether it is good to eat meat or to not eat meat; whether it is good to drink alcohol or not drink alcohol, etc. In the context of decolonialism is it good to attack science and modernity? Should one attack science and modernity, or should one not attack science and modernity, in this context? Ethics is the domain of normative disputes.

Comment: Do you know anything about Postcolonial theory? I don't think you do.

Comment: @CriglCragl Can you point out what's missing about Postcolonial theory?

Comment: @Frank: That it's about legacy power structures, not a bad-faith caricature that "modern standards of living" are "imposed customs and institutions in the form of colonialism".

Comment: "Should one attack science and modernity"? There's an old saying: "*don't bite the hand that feeds you.*" I used to walk past a plot of land with a sign saying it had achieved the highest yield on earth for some cereal crop. Unless you want to develop all your own methods to replace the ones you're rejecting, don't. If you do, what's the likelihood that you'll end up with the same stuff? How many ways are there to grow things, or make a better lightbulb?

Comment: @CriglCragl - Ms. Wexler, my first reading comprehension teacher, taught me to interpret the meaning of words and phrases in context. This article https://helpfulprofessor.com/postcolonialism-theory/ says, "[T]he term is used so freely that it becomes necessary for each author to define what they mean when they speak of postcolonial theory." The question does not define decolonialism or postcolonial theory. In terms of power patriarchal and matriarchal roles are observed by the child. The child must imitate or reject these roles while asking what is good and how should I act to cause the good?

Comment: @CriglCragl - This is what I wrote, "In other words, there was cultural conflict independent of the Westernized 'tribes' that imposed customs and institutions in the form of colonialism." Black Elk, a member of the Lakota peoples, describes other native peoples as his ancient enemies, even though a typical member of the invading Western culture would classify both cultures under the general term "Indians". Culture clash is not limited to Western colonial abuse of power. Western political-economic customs have accelerated scientific and technological progress that improve standards of living.

Comment: "progress that improve standards of living" - *for some*. Go to Pine Ridge Reservation. Go to the graveyards of those gifted smallpox-infused blankets. Oregon should still legally belong to Native Americans. History isn't 1 long glorious march towards progress. Niether has science been. Of course there've been non-colonial conflicts. But as this whole thread shows, people have this blindspot about the *ongoing* legacy of Colonialism, & a conviction that how old European white men see the world is the best of all possible worlds. We can do better, is the point.

Comment: @CriglCragl Modern standards of living are extremely dependent on certain 'power structures'. You cannot have your highly nutritious foods, airconditioned homes and smartphones, let alone such luxuries as accessible quality healthcare, social-economical safeguards, democracy, etc, without accepting some societal reforms along lines that originated in countries that were once colonizers. Of course, whether these modern standards of living have anything to do with the colonial past to begin with, is a separate question.

Comment: @CrigCragl - I observe that the culture called the West accelerates scientific and technological progress compared to cultures that by distinct implication map to the non-West. I am not trying to justify this observation or deny the harm caused in a context of human power relations. The United States during World War 2 became a form of State Capitalism to beat Fascist State Capitalism. See World War 2 from Space (https://youtu.be/z2yzBba6QT4). About 14 minutes in it says the United States forced the British empire to decolonize. United States again accelerates after Soviets launch Sputnik.

Comment: @SystemTheory Is there really a culture that can be called "the West" without further qualification?

Comment: @Frank is there one that can be called "[American] Indian"? The more specific you want to be the more specific you have to be, but the broad swaths do also provide useful information

Comment: @SystemTheory: In China they invented gunpowder, magnetic compasses, canal locks, & paper, while Europe was in the Dark Ages. Just because a given model of politics & economics has worked, doesn't mean it will keep working - new systems can arise, & Postcolonial Theory tries to look at how. And our goal should be to live well together, not just have gadgets. By many measures, the US is a failure at that for at least it's poorest 20%, who effectively don't live in a developed country (eg infant mortality below Cuba, never mind Europe).

Comment: @CriglCragl *As the accomplishments of the era came to be better understood in the 19th and the 20th centuries, scholars began restricting the Dark Ages appellation to the Early Middle Ages (c. 5th–10th century),[1][5][6] and today's scholars also reject its usage for the period.[7] The majority of modern scholars avoid the term altogether due to its negative connotations, finding it misleading and inaccurate.[8][9][10][11][12]*

Answer (score 3):

No wonder as Mark Fisher observed "It is easier to imgine the end of the world, than the end of Capitalism." Because, Capitalism is so poorly defined in most discourse, that it has this power to shapeshift in endless ways, that tend to turn perceptions of it into a projection. Discussed here: [Philosophers on alternatives to capitalism and communism](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/67075/philosophers-on-alternatives-to-capitalism-and-communism/72357#72357) The future is going to involve money, stock-owned companies with tradable shares, and people pursuing wealth. Not only are those things highly functional, they aren't intrinsically problematic, and accepting them doesn't prevent scope for radical political and economic innovation. Rolling everything bad about modernity into a boogie man and calling it Capitalism hinders rather helps change.

See this answer on some context about the motivations and methods of Postcolonial philosophy:
[Need help with this paper on epistemic justice](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/87224/need-help-with-this-paper-on-epistemic-justice/87228#87228)

Postcolonial thinking grew out of Postmodernism and Poststructuralism. Those included challenging the simplistic assumptions about the unity power and authority of science, and personally I see the challenge part as important. Dawkins for instance often oversteps the mark into Scientism, and projects his suspect views about society and gender as though no one could possibly disagree.

But, there is a problematic strand, exemplified by Kuhn, of claiming science is *only* ever a power struggle. Discussed here: [Why is postmodernism apparently so ill-perceived in philosophy of science?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/72864/why-is-postmodernism-apparently-so-ill-perceived-in-philosophy-of-science/86184#86184)

Thinkers like Haraway with The Cyborg Manifesto, and eorks like Primate Visions: Gender, Race, and Nature in the World of Modern Science, show that building on  critucal ideas about race and gender that motivate Postcolonial philosophy, don't have to mean 'questioning' the science, though it does the culture of the scientists.

> "Science is euro-centric in its core"

Absolutely not. I don't accept that at all. See [Scientific Method in the Islamic World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_in_the_medieval_Islamic_world) which included the first statement we can recognise as Scientific Method, and especially [Ibn al-Haytham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_al-Haytham)'s foundational and influential work in optics which directly inspired Newton. Gunpowder and magnetic compasses, which no less than Francis Bacon called two of the three cornerstones of the Modern Age, were invented by Daoist alchemists in China, who's work was preserved in Buddhist libraries. More fundamentally, science has always focused on dispensing with the role of identity as authority, and the cultural biases of parochial thinking - it is intrinsically internationalist. See [Can one speak unambiguously of "The" Scientific Method?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31942/can-one-speak-unambiguously-of-the-scientific-method/73819#73819) for more on the issues.

I think broadly speaking you confuse critiquing discourse and culture of scientists, with criticising science. If you disagree, please provide examples. I don't know any, other than Kuhn.

Comment: But the question is, can this "dispensing with the role of identity as authority" be deconstructed as in fact concealing an intention to dominate? "Objectivity" becomes just the latest way to oppress other cultures.

Comment: In a very real sense, if some culture doesn't care about "objectivity" or "evidence", shouldn't they be free to reject science? What's left of their voices if science becomes the dominant, global culture?

Comment: @BobaFit It's not so simple. There are very worthwhile ideas in some authors that can be classified as "postmodern". Lyotard is one, for example. Might be worth reading a bit of him.

Comment: @Frank Certainly not. Lyotard denies the possibility of knowledge. I will take him as his own best evaluator.

Comment: @BobaFit But if you scratch the surface a little and try to see what he really means, nothing interesting to think about? "Lyotard denies the possibility of knowledge. Case closed." seems a bit simplistic to me. And what if he was right about the impossibility of knowledge anyway? Why is it a given that knowledge is possible?

Comment: @ScottRowe The Holocaust was culture. Now re-consider whether culture matters.

Comment: @ScottRowe Maybe culture is a language shared by a group of people, where "language" is to be understand broadly as a set of concepts, ideas, attitudes, feelings that can be expressed using some form of language, spoken, written or otherwise used to exchange those concepts, ideas, ... between people in the group?

Comment: @ScottRowe: Maybe worth it's own question. I'd identify the origins of culture in the 'reprogramming' of shame & disgust, to serve social purposes, discussed here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77168/how-do-ethicists-tackle-the-question-is-it-immoral-to-have-sex-in-public-places/77170#77170 What is sacred, what is taboo

Answer (score 2):

Science is not by its nature a colonialist enterprise. But perhaps the scientific establishment that developed in the West did so as a byproduct of colonialism.

That says nothing of the scientific establishments that developed elsewhere. Like China. China is a country the size of Europe that developed pretty much independently. They had their own science.

In any case, the answer is no. Decolonialists do not have to attack science and modernity. Rather than attacking it, they could spread science and modernity to other places that are former colonies.

Comment: Oh, but it is a colonialist enterprise of the first order, because it is highly "universalizing", it presents itself as Truth to everybody, everywhere and anytime, recruiting objectivity and evidence to justify its dictums: its meta-narrative is that it is as universal as nature itself, but that is just a way to impose its narratives on others. Phew! ;-) (not that I believe this, but I'm gathering that would be a possible postmodern understanding of science and its relationship to politics and power)

Comment: @Frank Ooof, take that postmodernists.

Comment: @Frank If my friends said something like that to me I would kindly ask them to express themselves without using buzzwords (specialist terminology) and also to give some examples of what that mean, so we can have a nice conversation.

Comment: The buzzwords come with the territory in postmodernism ;-)

Comment: @Frank Then I suggest when they start talking like that you wink and start explaining integration using functorial diagrams..

Comment: They might like it. They might also want to import category theory into social science ;-)

Comment: @Frank Then God help us all.

Comment: @Frank What is postmodernism?

Comment: @user253751 "That postmodernism is indefinable is a truism. However, it can be described as a set of critical, strategic and rhetorical practices employing concepts such as difference, repetition, the trace, the simulacrum, and hyperreality to destabilize other concepts such as presence, identity, historical progress, epistemic certainty, and the univocity of meaning." from: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/postmodernism/

Comment: @Frank this is reminding me of the deranged ramblings of a certain Canadian former professor...

Comment: @Frank Eww. . . The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.

Comment: @Daron What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Frank The articles are highly technical and badly focused. As someone familiar with the thrust of many philosophies, I have never been able to use the SEP to learn anything.

Comment: @Frank Here's a [random example](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/stoicism/#BodiInco): "

Stoicism was one of the dominant philosophical systems of the Hellenistic period. The name derives from the porch (stoa poikilê) in the Agora at Athens decorated with mural paintings, where the first generation of Stoic philosophers congregated and lectured. "

Comment: You need to know what Hellenistic and Agora mean to understand the first sentence. Even though you don't need this knowledge to grasp stoicism. There is a pointless reference to the etymology on line two of the article, and no reference to what the philosophy actually IS in the opening paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

This debate is apparently based on loose terminology. Here, some definitions and ideas that might help.

**Modernity** is a period in history, which started with the *Enlightenment* and ended around 1950, *postmodernity* becoming right after; commonly associated with a loss of religious and moral values against individualism and scientific and technical developments. So, *Capitalism* is debatably a consequence of it, not a cause of it, it is not Capitalism that raised a (scientifical-technical) period in history.

**Colonialism** is the practice by which a territory and a human group are subject to a foreign rule; colonialism is sometimes associated with an evolved form of animal territorial domination (cf. Fanon), which raises directly from Darwinian mechanisms. According to your friends, this is the cause of all evil; the problem is easy to solve: they can just derogate all Darwinian laws in the Congress. Oh, wait. I forget there's no universal congress. And no congress which rules animal instinctive laws (we are in part animals). And no congress that accepted Darwinian laws of evolution and survival. And no congress members proposing alternatives to the *survival of the fittest* rule.

**Capitalism** means essentially the tendency to *accumulation of capital*, which includes the means of production, rights of ownership, free market development, natural resources, and not just that, but mainly a bunch of histories that only exist in our heads, like money, laws, power, status, etc. There is also has a good solution to this "problem", that proposed by Pol Pot, and which results are already available in history books. They can also read about Ceausescu, Mao Zedong, Stalin, Maduro, Castro, Allende, the Kim Jongs, Mariam, Hoxha, Ortega, Morales, etc. But warn them ALL cases are failures.

**Science is some type of knowledge** (that obtained according to the *Scientific Method*). **Technology** is the application of such knowledge in practice, and **Art** (not as aesthetics, but as in state-of-the-arts) is the application of those two for social benefit.

From here on, this is necessarily an opinion with some philosophical sustain. Politically, this issue is largely debatable.

Call this *The Natural Test*: The deepest of our instincts is to survive, and that is normally consistent with all our emotions and reason. When any living being, any individual, any human group, etc. tries a new rule, it is just tested by nature: either that being survives or not. Some specific groups that have submitted new ideas to *The Natural Test* and ended up with huge amounts of deaths: the FARC; the Aum Shinrikyo cult; Ugandan LRA; North Korea; Jim Jones people's temple; the Khmer Rouge; Nazism, etc.

There's no point in attacking science, tech and art. Europe developed a culture for knowledge, which is a positive achievement, not a failure. Anyway, science has been always developed, all along history, in all places where humans existed. If they don't like scientific colonialism, they just need to invent the wheel from scratch, and all remaining science and technology as well.

About “colonial technology”: just ask your friends to throw their laptops, TVs and mobile phones to a river. That way, they will be getting back their sovereignty.

> Why are decolonialist attacking science and modernity?

The big philosophical issue here is *responsibility*.

By definition, any *responsible* individual takes responsibility of what happens for himself. The responsibility to address social problems, the responsibility to solve individual and social issues. Then, he acts on it, without blaming or without complaining (blaming and complaining is just energy waste). For example: are there poverty issues? Ok, propose solutions without blaming and complaining. Many organizations do so and get it successfully. Your friends need to read about *Médecins Sans Frontières*, Water.org, Acumen, Heifer, Grameen Bank, etc.

By definition, individuals which feel *non-responsible* for what currently happens, can't take responsibility; instead, they look for blame. A lot of politicians do so. This approach produces social polarization and usually gets a lot of votes. But this approach does not propose solutions. And if they have done so, they have been submitted to *The Natural Test* and have failed. They nevertheless insist: Pablo Iglesias (Spain), Maduro (Venezuela), Corbyn (UK), Mélenchon (La France Insoumisse), Máximo Kirschner (Argentina), Correa, Diaz-Canel...

Sorry for this, not personal, but for me, your friends are typical examples of individuals in the second group. They are looking for who to blame -don't understand what for, perhaps to kill or imprison them-. If they believe in their ideas, they need to *practice* them. If they don't apply them, and they provide excuses, they don't really believe them. In such case, their discourse is not based on rationality, but on dogmas, blaming, complaining, use of excuses and personal attacks. Their discourse is evidently explained by personal frustration (causes them to point their failures elsewhere) and resentment (causes them to attack others). You can justify your position, but such kind of people will always find excuses to avoid doing what they say they believe. The arguments are as follows.

Decolonialism has failed. Deglobalization has and will always fail (maturity is not about isolation; it's not about dependence, it's not about independence: it's about interdependence). Open doors are always good, even if we don't use them; we want them to be open and use them for good. The best examples are North Korea, Cuba, Venezuela and Argentina. They reject modernity (we are not anymore there, anyway, your friends can just create their own social experiments, living like in 1700), capitalism (ask them to give the example, stop accumulating capital and share all their goods, right now!). When they pay taxes, they are supporting colonialism. Ask them to stop buying foreign products, stop paying taxes, stop using the internet, stop learning foreign languages, etc. Otherwise (if your friends don't act, dont donate their goods, don't crush their mobile phones, don't go living in communist kibbutz), those are just empt y words, which just expose their frustrations and anguish of blaming other for their own fails. Not trying to be mean here, but this is a common and predictable social pattern based on dogmas, which provides good amounts of votes to the left.

As a consequence, notice that the left wing has an ideology, but most voters are not serious about it (most don't even know it, otherwise, they would act critically about it -see spanish Ramon Rallo's daily criticism to left wing ideas, which is impressive, he just wrote a book about the fallacies of Marxism-): left-wing voters are serious mostly about confronting and harming the right wing. Just that.

For me, *left* means: *the survival of the group prevails over the individual*, which is just a natural mechanism based on majority (e.g. if I kill someone, I want to live, the group wants to kill me, so, the group wins). Taking that into account, I identify myself as such kind of leftist, which do implies complete logical consistency with capitalism, globalism, Darwinian laws, science, tech and art, etc., and mainly... *responsibility* (no blaming, no complaining, just acting silently to solve issues).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146070/discussion-on-answer-by-rodolfoap-do-decolonialists-have-to-attack-science-and-m); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The development of science has arised out of Colonial enterpises, and yes, an impression may be given that Colonial enterpises are the reasons why science exists, especially when you belong to a minority group. This is further compounded by the fact that, in most of these colonized places, the people  there have to climb ladders of success which are essentially the white man's creation. See  established forums were Science is discussed (eg: this site itself), Journals and so on.

To overcome this, is in my opinion a difficult issue. There is, on top of the aforementioned issues, foundational issues in that these colonized places may not have enough infastructure and funding to support people to do a science. The other angle of this, is that of brain drain, any one who would be exceptional would be taken up by the lands which were previously oppresive/ colonist due to the fact that they are able to provide more opportunities and infastructure.  This leads to decay of local scientists in many lands. See, eg: how working in FAANG companies is glorified by those in third world countres.

I believe, fundamentally, to rise out of these issues, there must be a belief insuinated by society for a minority of "I can do it too!", insuinated, for example, by media, and further by popular culture. Also, there must be a real meat to these efforts, for instance, the state should, actually produce instituitions through which the minority can rise up and achieve success.

Comment: This Answer helped me see more of what the current complaint is about: trying to succeed in an environment warped by prior policies and success of an outside group. It's the warping that is the problem, not the specific things that came from the prior policies.

Comment: +1 brain drain is a real problem

Comment: Well anywhere anyone can achieve success. More specific terms and premises are needed for a proper arguement@Boba Fit

Comment: @BobaFit Not sure what is the association between "state" and "media"?

Comment: I mean state in sense of the institutions external to an individual,  not as in government @Boba it

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom I look forward to you rewriting your answer.

Comment: I had at the time of posting the answer, rest of the points still stand as is I think @BobaFit

Comment: @BobaFit It can be, if the state is held sufficiently accountable. I believe a lot of small countries or other localities often have publicly-funded media simply because that's the only way it will get funded. They also tend to have more accountable institutions by virtue of their small size.

Comment: The wording is minorly changed.  "The state" is the government. In a society where the state produces institutions, the one thing you can count on is tyranny. Sooner or later and mostly always sooner.